# FluentValidation - how to have one entity property value drive another entities validation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluentvalidation

I have an object that consists of a number of properties and a number of collections a simplified example:

```
"Form": {
  "Funders": [
    {
      "FunderID": "string",
      "Name": "string",
      "Type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "Publications": [
    {
      "PublicationID": "string",
      "Name": "string",
      "Type": "string",
    }
  ],
  "Created": "2017-02-10T22:26:49.528Z",
  "CreatedBy": "string",
  "LastModified": "2017-02-10T22:26:49.528Z",
  "LastModifiedBy": "string",
}
```

How can I validate `Publications` has at least 1 `Publication` of `Type` Z if any Funder in `Funders` has a `Type` of A using fluent validation.

Stated a different way if any Funder Type is of type A then one of the Publication in Publications must be of Type Z

Currently I have validators for Publication, Funder, and form just struggling to figure out how to create this validation.

I am using fluentvalidation, c#, entity framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to perform the validation from your validation on the entire model.  It is actually pretty simple.

```
   RuleFor(x => x.Publications
   .Where(p => p.Type == "Type Z").Count()).GreaterThan(0)
   .When(x => x.Funders.Where(f => f.Type == "Type A").Count() > 0)
   .WithMessage("An Form containing a funder of type 'Type A' must have at least one Publication with of type 'Type Z'.")
   .OverridePropertyName("Publications");
```